# Visual Studio Online build fail after argument change

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have a build configured on visual studio online that was working great until I set the following msbuild arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
/p:WebPublishMethod=Package
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
/p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)"
```

The error I get is:
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (2205, 5) Copying file Views\Web.config to obj\Stage\CSAutoParameterize\original\Views\Web.config failed. Could not find a part of the path 'Views\Web.config'.

I noticed on the build logs, that this file was not included in the "Get sources" stage. Have no idea, why the error appears only when publish parameters are set.

Any Ideas?

PS: I am using this arguments to prepare the project for continuous deployment.

Comment: It means exactly what it says. It couldn't find a particular file.

Comment: @DanielMann and why this file is now missing only because I set publishing? Note that before adding this parameters, compilation was successful.

Comment: Probably because it's explicitly mentioned in the package configuration?

Comment: The missing file (and some others) where not added to source control. My bad here. How was it working before is an open question.

Comment: @IgorKondrasovas, after you check in the Web.config file, will you get this issue resolved?

Comment: @Vicky Yes. After checking in all missing files I got not more build errors.